# How can i make innerHtml writes error only once?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, innerhtml

I have a problem, I made a form validation in javascript and after all validation checks I put `innerHtml += "actually error message"` and the problem is how many times I click the submit button it writes out the message. Someone can help me to solve this? Or make this more elegant or better logic. I'm a beginner.

```js
function regvalidate() {

  var errortable = document.getElementById('log');

  var x = document.forms["regform"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["regform"]["email"].value;
  var z = document.forms["regform"]["pass1"].value;
  var b = document.forms["regform"]["pass2"].value;

  if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "" || b == "") {
    errortable.innerHTML = 'Cant be empty field';
    return false;
  }

  var regexEmail = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
  var email = document.getElementById("email");

  if (regexEmail.test(email.value)) {} else {
    errortable.innerHTML += 'Invaild email address';
    return false;

  }

  password1 = regform.pass1.value;
  password2 = regform.pass2.value;

  if (password1 != password2) {
    errortable.innerHTML += 'Two pass dosent match';
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
<form id="regform" class="form-signin" action="#" method="post">

  <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username">

  <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">

  <input type="password" id="pass1" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password_1">

  <input type="password" id="pass2" class="form-control" placeholder="password again" name="password_2">
  </br>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onClick="return regvalidate()" name="register_btn">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Just use `=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: Rather than `+=` you could just use `errortable.innerHTML = "thing"`.  That would let you show one error at a time.

Comment: Why did you use `+=` in the first place if you didn't want to add to what was already there?

Comment: `+=` becomes errortable.innerHTML + errortable.innerHTML = 'your string'
Just use `=` as everyone else pointed

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `+` before `=`like the following

```
errortable.innerHTML += 'Two pass dosent match';
```

or do it like

```
errortable.innerHTML = '';
errortable.innerHTML += 'Two pass dosent match';
```